# How to rename a file when it arrives in a specific folder?

Tags: playwright, autoit, file-rename

I'm using Playwright to record test videos and save them to a specific folder. You aren't able to rename these video files when they're made in Playwright, but I need file names to be date and time of recording. In AutoIt how to rename a file to the `FileGetTime()` return once it's added to the Playwright videos folder?

I tried `FileFindFirstFile(! "2023")` to find files that haven't been renamed already. Then `FileGetTime()` to get the string I want to rename it as. Then a `FileMove()` to rename file to the time while keeping it in same folder.

Answer (score -1):

> "*I tried `FileFindFirstFile(! "2023")` to find files* …"

Consider using [`_FileListToArray()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileListToArray.htm) instead.

> "… *files that haven't been renamed already.*"

Use [`StringRegExp($sFileName, '^\d{14}\.', $STR_REGEXPMATCH)`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm) (and/or `$FC_NOOVERWRITE` on [`FileMove()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileMove.htm)) instead.

> "*In AutoIt how to rename a file to the `FileGetTime()` return* …"

Example:

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_sFolder = 'C:\location\'

FileRenameDateTimeCreated($g_sFolder)
ShellExecute($g_sFolder)

Func FileRenameDateTimeCreated(Const $sFolder, Const $sFilter = '')
    Local Const $aFile = _FileListToArray($sFolder, $sFilter, $FLTA_FILES, False)
    Local       $sName = ''

    For $i1 = 1 To $aFile[0]

        If StringRegExp($aFile[$i1], '^\d{14}\.', $STR_REGEXPMATCH) Then _
        ContinueLoop

        $sName = FileGetTime($sFolder & $aFile[$i1], $FT_CREATED, $FT_STRING) _
               & StringRight($aFile[$i1], StringInStr($aFile[$i1], '.', 0, -1))

        FileMove($sFolder & $aFile[$i1], $sFolder & $sName, $FC_NOOVERWRITE)

    Next

EndFunc
```